# I've got a blue exclamation in the title bar and it won't go away

Tags: updates, indicator

12.04

Every time I boot my machine, theres a blue exclamation point on the top right, to the left of the standard indicators. When I click it, it says "Information available". Clicking on that opens a window with a bunch of mixed English / Japanese / Hebrew / whatever text and at the bottom there's something legible:

"The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.

flashplugin-installer

The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download again now.  Running this command requires an active Internet connection."

The update doesn't work, so the icon keeps coming back.

I don't think flash is working in my browser, but right now I couldn't care less. What do I click to get rid of the pointless blue exclamation mark?

Comment: Can you get a screenshot and post it here?

Answer (score 0):

Open Ubuntu Software Center and search for Flash. Uninstall it, and the warning should go away.